# Concatenate the nested arrays within a single 2d array, element-wise

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, concatenation, elementwise-operations

I have a numpy array like this:

```
array = [[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

I would like to concatenate them element-wise. Most of the solutions I have found are able to do this with two separate 2d arrays, but I would like to do this within a single 2d array.

Desired output:

```
array = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: Is `array` a numpy array, or a list of lists? Looks like you just want the array transpose.  `list(zip(*...)` js a list version of transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just only line code

```
array = [[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
print(list(zip(*array)))
```

output :

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

ljdyer is almost right, but you have only one array, so you can do this:

```
list(zip(*array))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `zip` operation. Try:

```
arr1 = [1, 3, 5, 7]
arr2 = [2, 4, 6, 8]
print(list(zip(arr1,arr2)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

---

Or for numpy arrays you have the `stack` operation:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
b = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])

c = np.stack((a,b), axis = 1)

print(c)
```

See https://www.delftstack.com/howto/numpy/python-numpy-zip/

Comment: Unfortunately, I am trying not to split it into separate arrays. I'd like to do this to the nested arrays within a single 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will concatenate array element wise in each column

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]])
res = []
for i in range(array.shape[1]):
  res.append(array[:, i])
res = np.array(res)
print(res.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy transpose:

```
In [382]: np.transpose([[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]])
Out[382]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

If it already is a numpy array (as opposed to just a list of lists),you can use the `T` shortcut:

```
In [383]: arr = np.array([[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]])
In [384]: arr
Out[384]: 
array([[1, 3, 5, 7],
       [2, 4, 6, 8]])
In [385]: arr.T
Out[385]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

list-zip is a well known list version of transpose:

```
In [386]: list(zip(*arr))
Out[386]: [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Note the result is a list of tuples.